# How did Bruce Lee die?

Tags: mortality, celebrities, bruce-lee

[Bruce Lee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Lee) was an iconic actor and martial arts instructor who died at a young age.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Lee#Death) states:

> The preliminary opinion of Peter Wu, the neurosurgeon who saved Lee's life during his first seizure, was that the cause of death should have been attributed to either a reaction to cannabis or Equagesic. However, Wu later backed off from this position, stating that:
>
> Professor Teare was a forensic scientist recommended by Scotland Yard; he was brought in as an expert on cannabis and we can't contradict his testimony. The dosage of cannabis is neither precise nor predictable, but I've never known of anyone dying simply from taking it.

What are the facts? How can the death of someone like Bruce Lee still be a mystery?

Comment: Not sure we can add anything to the comment of the forensic scientist who was on the case.

Comment: It isn't reasonable to assume that 1973 forensic medicine should be able to precisely determine the cause of every death, even "someone like Bruce Lee".

Comment: There's nothing mysterious about not knowing something. You just don't know.

Comment: Not sure we can add anything to the comment of the forensic scientist who was on the case. –  Rory Alsop

Comment: Chuck Norris had a bad thought about him.